# Docusign Iframe is not loading

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

i have an iframe which shows docusign app . it was working fine . but sometime it just keep loading and in network tool i can see below request is failing

https://docucdn-a.akamaihd.net/olive/latest/css/olive.min.css -> ERR connection time out

is it something missing in my app or in docusign ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing embedded signing through an Iframe? If so, I would recommend against using IFrames all together. You should redirect the user to the provided embedded URL instead.

There are features that are not supported in IFrames.

Comment: but why do it works for sometimes ? and not working when tried after few min ?